# Printing UIImage using AirPrint causes cut-off content

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, airprint

I am printing out a `UIImage` using AirPrint but the margins aren't correct. This is what it looks like when it prints:
[image: Photo of printout]

Is there a way I can make it fit perfectly on the paper?

Here's the code as requested:

```
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    //pic.delegate = del;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Ticket"];
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;


    pic.printingItem = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error." 
                                                   message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"An error occured while printing: %@", error]
                                                  delegate:nil 
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [av show];
            [av release];
        }
    };

    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: You probably need to show us your code.

Comment: If you are printing a `UIImage`, why aren't you setting `printInfo.outputType` to `UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto` instead of `UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to scale the image down to the ratio of the printed image, that way you can see the whole thing on the page.

There are several ways of doing this, so I will just tell you the way that I would do it. I maintain a class called [ANImageBitmapRep](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANImageBitmapRep) that has several different types of image scaling. The kind of scaling that you want keeps the entire image, but centers it inside of a rectangle of a certain size.  First, you must add the ANImageBitmapRep source files to your project, and #import *ANImageBitmapRep.h*:

```
#import "ANImageBitmapRep.h"
```

Then, scale the image like this:

```
pic.printingItem = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] imageFittingFrame:CGSizeMake(478, 640)];
```

You can change the `CGSizeMake(x, y)` to whatever you want, in order to adjust the scale and resolution of the scaled image.

Comment: Hi i sort of have the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578013/printing-uiimage-using-epos-sdk

Comment: just to add if OxSina had problems regarding the content being too big i think mine should be imageFillingFrame but i have a question if i would depend on the image.size.height the height of the printed outcome will be small and not enough to cover long content. any ideas? thanks