# Printing UIImage using ePOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, printing, epson

I'm using ePOS SDK from Epson which allows connecting to the printer (TM-T88V) via wifi. link for the sdk (http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm)

I'm loading an UIImage from a url using this code.

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:_url];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Then to Print the image (using ePOS) **NOTE: I will skip the connecting part since it is not included to my question.**

```
EposBuilder* builder = [EposBuilder alloc]  initWithPrinterModel:@"TM-T88V" lang:EPOS_OC_MODEL_ANK];

EposPrint* printer = [[EposPrint alloc] init];

int retVal = EPOS_OC_SUCCESS;
unsigned long status = 0;

retVal = [builder addImage:image X:0 Y:0 Width:image.size.width Height:image.size.Height Color: EPOS_OC_COLOR_1];

retVal = [printer sendData:builder Timeout:10000 Status:&status];
```

**Now my problem is that the printed result is alot smaller, see the size of the image is 271x368px. see image below for sample**

Any ideas on how to make it print properly? Also i've found this [Printing UIImage using AirPrint causes cut-off content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652082/printing-uiimage-using-airprint-causes-cut-off-content) which gave a link on scaling the image but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: i suggest you that create your bill image according to paper size

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, don't mine of you already resolved it, The thing i did was, to save the Image in Documents folder through `NSFileManager` and get the same from the documents folder and add a space to the image before adding, sorry for my english.. you need to implement your own code to save & retrive image through file manager.

```
NSData *dataFromUrl=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromUrl];
    if(image1)
    {
        [Filemanager saveReceiptLogoImage:image1];
    }
```

//IN printer class,

```
    UIImage *image1 = [Filemanager receiptLogo];
                if(image1)
                {
  result = [builder addText:@"    "];
   UIImage *resizedImage = [image1 resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(512, 350) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
                    result = [builder addImage:resizedImage X:0 Y:0 Width:MIN(512, resizedImage.size.width) Height:resizedImage.size.height Color:EPOS_OC_COLOR_1];
}
```

Comment: tried your approach. But the image is not that good in quality. Also iused UIViewContentModeScaleAspectToFill

Comment: can you show me your receipt photo and update your answer with resizedImageContentMode method