# Printing Pdf using AirPrint causes cut-off content

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiprintpagerenderer, uiprintinteractioncntrler

Here i am printing pdf with size 'pageSize = CGSizeMake(640, 832);'. this size is larget then A4 size page aspected. so i will cut-off some text(means it will not print whole page).

while printing same pdf using MAC, it will print whole page with help of option (scale to fit).  so can any one help me to come out from this problem.. is there any option in IOS sdk for scale to fit.

here is my code..

```
-(void)printItem
{

NSArray *aArrPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
NSString *aStr = [[aArrPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PropertyReport_%d.pdf",self.propertyId]];

  // NSString *aStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TRADUZIONE HELP SECTIONS REV2" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:aStr];
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:data])
{
    printController.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    //printInfo.jobName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Image"];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;

    printController.printingItem = data;




    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!completed && error)
        {
            //NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

  //  aWebViewPDF.hidden=FALSE;
    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As bizarre as it sounds try:

```
printController.showsPageRange = NO;
```

This seems to enable auto-scale, but sometimes prints an extra blank page at the end of the job. AirPrint is basically witchcraft.

Comment: Laughed out loud at your "witchcraft" comment.

Comment: Unbelievable. Setting ``printController.showsPageRange = YES;`` solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have only one option is to `scale down` to the `ratio` of the `printed format` from all pages of PDF then print it. I have done is got all pages of `pdf into images` and scaled that down to requirement :

```
NSString *strFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdftouch" ofType:@"pdf"];
pic.printingItems = [[self allPagesImageFromPDF:strFilePath] copy];
```

Add all three methods :

`Convert all PDF pages into UIImages`

```
-(NSMutableArray *)allPagesImageFromPDF:(NSString *)strPath
{
  NSMutableArray *arrImages = [NSMutableArray array];
  CGPDFDocumentRef pdf  = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath]);
  NSInteger numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
  for (NSInteger pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= numberOfPages;
     pageIndex++)
  {
    UIImage *img = [self getThumbForPage:pdf pageIndex:pageIndex];
    [arrImages addObject:[self resizedImage:img]];
  }
  return arrImages;
}
```

`Resize images`

```
-(UIImage *)resizedImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(612, 792)); //A4 size
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,612, 792)]; //A4 size
  UIImage *resizedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return resizedImg;
}
```

`Get UIImage from CGPDFPageRef`

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbForPage:(CGPDFDocumentRef)pdfRef pageIndex:(int)page_number{

  // Get the page
  CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef, page_number);
  // Changed this line for the line above which is a generic line

  CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);
  //CGFloat pdfScale = width/pageRect.size.width;
  //pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);
  pageRect.origin = CGPointZero;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  // White BG
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
  CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);

  CGContextSaveGState(context);

  // Next 3 lines makes the rotations so that the page look in the right direction

  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
  CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox, pageRect, 0, true));

  CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, myPageRef);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);

  UIImage *thm = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return thm;  
}
```

**EDIT** : Refer [printing-uiimage-using-airprint-causes-cut-off-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652082/printing-uiimage-using-airprint-causes-cut-off-content)

Comment: thanks for your response. but the problem is page size should be different according to its page formater(like A4, A5 etc). so we can't resize image for  single page type.so kindly suggest me option for auto scale as per print page formate.