# Print a UIImageView with AirPrint

Tags: ios, uiimageview, airprint

I have a `UIImageView` that contains a photo. I want to print the `UIImageView` with AirPrint. What should i do? Can I convert the photo into a PDF and after print the PDF? How can I try AirPrint with the iPhone Simulator?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652082/printing-uiimage-using-airprint-causes-cut-off-content

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the iOS simulator and go to the file settings. Then you can press "Open printer simulator."